# Using Encoded Polyline in a Google Maps Static Map Call

Tags: php, google-maps, google-polyline

Ok, maybe this is a stupid question but i spend hours and didn't find something to help me to discover this.
I'm using Google Maps Static Map to draw a map with many points in path, i'm doing one request like this one:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin.png|44.80006858,20.4791788&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin_destination_toolbar.png|44.8013566,20.4804733&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|44.80006858,20.4791788|44.80028333,20.47892833|44.80152833,20.48004833|44.80135667,20.48047333&format=jpg
```

Result:
[image]

Works fine! Now i'm trying to use Polylines to create a short request because google api limit is 2000 characters and for my app i have situations with more than 100 coordinates points to put in path.
I have the algorithm(PHP) to encode the coordinates in Polylines,after this i request again with the coordinates encoded.
The result for same request but with Polyline:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin.png|44.80006858,20.4791788&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin_destination_toolbar.png|44.8013566,20.4804733&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|m_mpG{y~{Bi@p@yF_F`@sA&format=jpg
```

Result:
[image]

Don't work...so my question here is: Can i use the encoded Polyline in that kind of call in Google API like i'm doing now without Polyline or i'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing the `enc:` before the encoded path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `enc:`: [static map with encoded string](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin.png%7C44.80006858,20.4791788&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin_destination_toolbar.png%7C44.8013566,20.4804733&path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7Cenc:m_mpG%7By%7E%7BBi@p@yF_F%60@sA&format=jpg)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin.png%7C44.80006858,20.4791788&markers=icon:http://api.appcargo.com/app_images/ic_pin_destination_toolbar.png%7C44.8013566,20.4804733&path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7Cenc:m_mpG%7By~%7BBi@p@yF_F%60@sA&format=jpg
```

[image]

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths):

> **Encoded Polylines**
>
> Instead of a series of locations, you may instead declare a path as an encoded polyline by using the **enc:** prefix within the location declaration of the path. Note that if you supply an encoded polyline path for a map, you do not need to specify the (normally required) center and zoom parameters.